# mysql sum query between interval

Tags: mysql, datetime, intervals

I have a little odd problem with a mysql query :)

This is my table:

```
mysql> describe meteo;

| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

| name      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |

| date      | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |

| value     | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

***My goal is this: create a query that sum all value from 14:00 to 16:00 stepping by 5 or 10 minutes.***

I do something that is near the solution doing this N time from (14:00 to 16:00)

```
SELECT sum(value)  FROM meteo WHERE date>='2016-09-9 14:30:00' AND date<='2016-09-9 14:35:00'

SELECT sum(value)  FROM meteo WHERE date>='2016-09-9 14:35:00' AND date<='2016-09-9 14:40:00'
```

...
and so on...

Exists a query that do this only giving the interval range?
I whould like to have something like this in the output:

```
2016-09-9 14:30:00 2016-09-9 14:35:00  176

2016-09-9 14:35:00 2016-09-9 14:40:00  2312
```

...

Thanks for help!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table min_interval

```
  id begin                 END
  1  2016-09-9 14:30:00    2016-09-9 14:35:00
  2  2016-09-9 14:35:00    2016-09-9 14:40:00
  3  2016-09-9 14:40:00    2016-09-9 14:45:00
```

You can look this post to see how generate a list of day, easy to change for minutes.

[generate days from date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)

and then

```
 SELECT m.begin, m.end, SUM(t.value)
 FROM min_interval m 
 LEFT JOIN meteo t
   ON t.date >= m.begin
  AND t.date < m.end
 GROUP BY m.begin, m.end
```

Comment: Thank for reply, but it's a little bit hard generate a table each time for a date! Maybe I should change way and do it into python!

Comment: You dont need a table, you can create a subquery. Did you check the generate days link?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use mysql date_add() function like this:

```
SELECT sum(value)  FROM meteo WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AND date
```

Comment: `sum all value from 14:00 to 16:00 stepping by 5 or 10 minutes.` ??

Comment: Sorry mis-read the question, this will not include the stepping process, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sum(value) from Meteo Where date >= currentDate 13:55 and date <= currentDate 16:10;
```